# Yii - Design question - Keeping dialoges separate from the main view file and accessing them

Tags: yii

I have a case where on my view file there are 6 links and clicking on them opens CJuiDialog boxes . I am keeping all the 6 dialog  boxes code in the same view file along with links and that is causing the file to be big and loading them all together once .The ideal scenario is the dialog boxes should get loaded only when the use clicks on the links .

So is there any way we can keep only the links code in the main view file and keeping all the dialogue boxes in separate files and loading them only when the user clicks on the links

I mean

```
index.php ( view containing only links)
_dialog1 ( containing code for first dialog )
_dialog2 ( containing code for second dialog )
_dialog3 ( containing code for third dialog )
_dialog4 ( containing code for fourth dialog )
_dialog5 ( containing code for fifth dialog )
_dialog6 ( containing code for sixth dialog )
```

**Sample Code**

```
//First Dialog code

     $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'modal'=>true,      
            ),
        ));

        echo 'First dialog content here';

        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

        echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
            'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog1").dialog("open"); return false;',
        ));

//2nd dialog code 

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog2',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'modal'=>true,      
            ),
        ));

        echo 'dialog2 content here';

        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

        echo CHtml::link('open dialog', '#', array(
            'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog2").dialog("open"); return false;',
        ));
```

**Solution I came with**

```
//In controller

       public function actionOpenDialog1()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->renderPartial('_dialogContent1', $data, false, true);
    }
       public function actionOpenDialog2()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->renderPartial('_dialogContent2', $data, false, true);
    }

//In index.view

<div id="data">
</div>

<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Open first dialog", CController::createUrl('dialogTesting/openDialog1'),array('update' => '#data'));

echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Open second dialog", CController::createUrl('dialogTesting/openDialog2'),array('update' => '#data'));
?>

//_dialogContent1.php

<?php

 $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>true,
                'modal'=>true,
            ),
        ));

        echo 'first dialog content here';

        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>


//_dialogContent2.php

<?php

 $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>true,
                'modal'=>true,
            ),
        ));

        echo 'first dialog content here';

        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: Can you paste your current usage of CJuiDialog? No need that you paste real html from _dialog1 to _dialog6, just in the place of content for dialog1 and dialog2 write "here is dialog1 html", "here is dialog2 html".

Comment: Thanks for your response . Added the code in question . That is from the index.php .Took for two dialogues and copied it here . In two dialogues just echoing some sample test ( to make things clearer ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My answer**

//In controller

```
   public function actionOpenDialog1()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->renderPartial('_dialogContent1', $data, false, true);
}
   public function actionOpenDialog2()
{
    $data = array();
    $this->renderPartial('_dialogContent2', $data, false, true);
}
```

//In index.view

'#data'));

echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Open second dialog", CController::createUrl('dialogTesting/openDialog2'),array('update' => '#data'));
?>

//_dialogContent1.php

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>true,
                'modal'=>true,
            ),
        ));

```
    echo 'first dialog content here';

    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

?>

//_dialogContent2.php

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
            'id'=>'mydialog1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'Dialog box 1',
                'autoOpen'=>true,
                'modal'=>true,
            ),
        ));

```
    echo 'first dialog content here';

    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

**Naming files**
The convention in Yii is to name the view files:

- `index.php`: a full view
- `_dialog1.php`: a partial view (included from another view)

**Sub views**
Then you can include partial views with `CController::renderPartial()`:

```
$this->beginWidget(...);
$this->renderPartial('_dialog1', array('var1' => 23, 'var2' => "var"));
$this->endWidget(...);
```

**Factorizing code**
This should make your source node much lighter. But I suggest you go farther and avoid duplicating all those widget calls. To do this, you should define a structure for your dialog parameters and loop over it. Something like:

```
$dialogs = array(
    'mydialog1' => array(
        'file' => '_dialog1',
        'options' => array('title' => "My title 1",),
    ),
    'mydialog2' => array(
        'file' => '_dialog12,
        'options' => array('title' => "My title 2",),
    ),
);
$defaultOptions = array(
    'autoOpen' => false,
    'modal' => true,      
);
foreach ($dialogs as $id => $dialog) {
    $this->beginWidget(
        'zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',
        array(
            'id' => $id,
            'options' => CMap::mergeArray($defaultOptions, $dialog['options']),
        )
    );
    // ... include partial view ...
```

This factorization will make your code more compact, but it will above simplify the future changes. Using data structures to avoid code duplication is a well-known practice.

**AJAX**
Lastly, if you really want the partial views to be loaded dynamically, that means you have to use AJAX. Be careful, because your page may be less reactive from a user point of view. If all your forms amount to a few Kb of HTML, then there's no nedd for AJAX. But if you go this way, then you'll need to:

- Add an CJuiDialog containing just `<div id="dialog-ajax"></div>`.
- Create another action that will apply `renderPartial()` on the dialog views.
- Replace the content of the previous foreach loop with code that writes JS like `function dialog1() {jQuery("#dialog-ajax").load(...);}`. You'll need to hack if you want to change dynamically the widget title.
- Bind some events (clicks) to these JS functions.

Another way would be to make your aJAX action render a full CJuiDialog, it might be simpler and avoid JS hacks. Anyway, I'm not sure you really need AJAX.

Comment: Thank You Mytskine, I came with some solution and posted it in my question . Do you think the one I came is fine ? Once again thanks . With the approach I posted on firefox 3.6 seeing some issues :( . First two times it is working and then , not getting the window

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include one empty `CJuiDialog` in your page, and when it needs to be displayed load the contents with jQuery AJAX ([`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is the simplest, and probably enough) that returns a render of the appropriate view before opening the dialog.

Comment: Thank You Jon , I came with some solution and posted it in my question . Do you think this one is better or as you said using load is better? Sorry bit confused with the approach you explained . any code snippet that helps ? Once again thanks . With the approach I posted on firefox 3.6 seeing some issues :(